# Unable to compile C++ program with Clang-14

Tags: c++, linux, clang, clang++, llvm-ir

I am currently trying to compile a small program I have been working on with Clang and am getting the following error on compilation using `scons` as the build system:

```bash
/usr/bin/clang++ -o src/PluGen/main.o -c -std=c++17 -fPIC -I. -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fpermissive -fopenmp --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fpermissive -fPIC -I. -O2 -flto -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -DHAVE_PYTHON -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DLARGE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_PERL -DREENTRANT -DHAVE_R -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.10 -I/usr/lib/perl5/5.36/core_perl/CORE -I/usr/include/R -I/usr/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include -I/usr/lib/R/library/RInside/include -I/usr/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include -I/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/library/RInside/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib src/PluGen/main.cxx
...
/usr/bin/clang++ -o PluGen/plugen -rdynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.36/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now src/PluGen/main.o src/PluGen/PluginGenerator.o -L/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.36/core_perl/CORE -L/usr/lib/R/lib -L/usr/lib/R/library/RInside/lib -L/usr/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -L/usr/local/lib/R/library/RInside/lib -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -Llib -lc -lc++ -lstdc++fs
src/PluGen/main.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`main.o` is being generated as a IR bitcode

```bash
file src/PluGen/main.o
src/PluGen/main.o: LLVM IR bitcode
```

Running the linker outside of the `scons` builder yields the following message:

```bash
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie -export-dynamic --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o PluGen/plugen /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/crtbeginS.o -L/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.36/core_perl/CORE -L/usr/lib/R/lib -L/usr/lib/R/library/RInside/lib -L/usr/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -L/usr/local/lib/R/library/RInside/lib -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -Llib -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib -E -rpath /usr/lib/perl5/5.36/core_perl/CORE -O1 --sort-common --as-needed -z relro -z now src/PluGen/main.o src/PluGen/PluginGenerator.o -lc -lc++ -lstdc++fs -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/crtendS.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
src/PluGen/main.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
```

The program *does* compile correctly using GCC. Just not with Clang.

What is going on?

Comment: Object files (files ending with the `.o` suffix) are fully compiled translation units, translated to the target systems binary code. On Linux they are in ELF format. LLVM IR code (in source or binary form) are not considered object files, and the linker can't handle such files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `-flto` when compiling, but not when linking. `clang` can't do that. `-c -flto` compiles to LLVM IR bitcodes which the linker cannot use directly. You should either drop `-flto` everywhere, or use it everywhere.

```
$ clang++ -flto -c hello.cpp
$ file hello.o
hello.o: LLVM IR bitcode
$ clang++ -o hello hello.o && echo Ok
hello.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
$ clang++ -o hello hello.o -flto && echo Ok
Ok
```

`gcc` works differently. It compiles to "fat objects" with both machine code and internal compiler representation baked in. Linker can use these, and apply the LTO plugin automatically.

```
$ g++ -c hello.cpp -flto
$ file hello.o
hello.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
$ g++ -o hello hello.o && echo Ok
Ok
```